# How to create coloured smoke effect for logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

I'd like to recreate the effect used in this picture.
How can I do this in Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: It's an illustration more than anything. While the effect is part of it, the actual implementing of the illustration is likely 90% of the challenge here.

Comment: I voted down this question because there's like gazillion tutorials about smoke that can be found with 3 seconds of googling "photoshop smoke tutorial" and then theres the obvious, brushes. ( Granted that it has some watercolor'ish feature's, but still )

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to achieve this effect you can get such brushes in-case you need them..

- [Smoke Brush](http://qbrushes.net/photoshop-abstract-brushes/21-smoke-brush-set/)
- [Smoke photographs change color in Photoshop](http://www.ephotozine.com/article/colour-your-incense-smoke-photographs-in-photoshop-13056)
- [50 Smoke art Tutorial & brushes](http://www.photoshopwebsite.com/photoshop-tutorials/50-smoke-effects-photoshop-tutorials/)
- [Realistic smoke effect tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/realistic-smoke-effect-photoshop-tutorials/)

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the original author simply used the liquify command on a stock image (or lifted image) of actual smoke.

Then simply apply a gradient overlay for color.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a photo of smoke, mirrored with a gradient colour overlay.